# git submodule - should not have been updated. How to back down

Tags: git, git-submodules

When using "git submodule" I get myself into a new problem
I have .gitmodules file within my git project "mainproject"

```
[submodule "subsystem1"]
  path = subsystem11
  url = /mnt/gitrepos/subsystem1.git/
```

Starting in my main project I did

```
$ cd subsystem1
$ git pull origin master
```

Lets assume that something is really wrong now in "submodule1". 
I got many updates in, that I did not like to have (right now).

```
$ cd .. #back in "mainproject"
$ git status  
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   subsystem1 (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How can I revert to the version of subsystem1 that I had before pulling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't committed the changes to the submodule in your main project, `git submodule update` from the parent repo will revert the submodule to its previous state.

Comment: I have found that  "git submodule update" clears the branch in the submodule (you are no longer on branch). When you get happy with the submodule be sure to checkout the branch where the happy commit is and then in the project commit that version of the submodule

Comment: a submodule is a pointer to a specific commit in some other repository; running `git submodule update` is the same as checking out that commit from inside the submodule. committing a submodule from inside a parent repo updates the pointer